# Prove that $R \geq min(R_1, R_2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let's say that we have two series, $\sum_{n=1} ^\infty a_n z^n$ and $\sum_{n=1} ^\infty b_n z^n$, each with radius of convergence $R_1$ and $R_2$. Now, suppose that $R$ is the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1} ^\infty (a_n + b_n) z^n$. I wish to show that $R \geq min(R_1, R_2)$ by basic properties of convergence.

I know that two convergent series can be broken up like this:

$$\sum_{n=1} ^\infty (a_n + b_n) = \sum_{n=1} ^\infty a_n + \sum_{n=1} ^\infty b_n$$

However, I know from a previous question I asked (which can be found here: [Radii of convergence for complex series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709384/radii-of-convergence-for-complex-series)), that the right hand side isn't equal to the left hand side, necessarily. So, how would I use basic properties of convergence to show what I need to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $R<\min\{R_1,R_2\}$. Then we can find a real number $R<r<\min\{R_1,R_2\}$ and a $z_0$ with $|z_0|=r$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n+b_n||z_0|^n$ diverges.

However, the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n||z_0|^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|b_n||z_0|^n$ converge because $|z_0|=r<\min\{R_1,R_2\}$, so it follows that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(|a_n|+|b_n|)|z_0|^n$ converges. But $|a_n+b_n|\leq |a_n|+|b_n|$, so the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n+b_n||z|^n$ converges by the comparison test, which is the desired contradiction.