# Can the Radius of Convergence be strictly greater than 1?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider the series found in this question: [Prove that $R \geq min(R_1, R_2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719304/prove-that-r-geq-minr-1-r-2)

Now, consider that $R_1 \lt R_2 $. I would then like to determine if the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1} ^ \infty (a_n + b_n) z^n$ has to be strictly greater than $R_1$, or if equality can occur.

I was thinking that perhaps I should use similar properties of convergence demonstrated in the above question posted. Is that true, or am I missing a necessary piece of information here?

Answer (score 3):

The series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\quad\hbox{and}\quad
  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Bigl(\frac z2\Bigr)^n$$
have radius of convergence $1$ and $2$ respectively.  The sum
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \Bigl(1+\frac1{2^n}\Bigr)z^n$$
has radius of convergence $1$.

**Added in response to comment**.  In fact, if $R_1<R_2$ then $R$ always equals $R_1$.  Sketch of proof: if $R_1<\rho<R_2$ and the sum converges at $\rho$, then so does the difference of series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (a_n+b_n)z^n-\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nz_n
  =\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n\ ,$$
contrary to the assumption that the first series diverges beyond $R_1$.

Comment: Great, thank you! Out of curiosity though, is there any formal way I can prove this? That is, what properties will allow equality to be the case?

Comment: See extended answer.

Comment: Terrific! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @David, I thought that for complex series, you could not break up series like you did. Can you please explain a bit more how you were justified in doing $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_{n}+b_{n})z^{n} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}z_{n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}$? thank you.

Comment: @JessyCat do you understand it for real series?  It is exactly the same for complex series.

Comment: @David, oh I understand it for real series. I was just under the impression that it was different for complex ones.